# Mocking an object created inside a method during a PHPunit test

Tags: php, soap, phpunit

I am currently trying to extend the unittesting coverage of my work application and I am facing an issue with an existing service sending data to a SOAP api. I want to mock the \SoapClient Object, which is created inside the very method I want to test.

Right now I fail to find a way to set a mock to replace the real SoapClient object. The mocked object is a simple mock of the UploadFlight method which should return "true".

Here you can see the method :

```php
    public function sendPreflightPlanning()
    {
        $doc = $this->getPreflightPlanning();

        $client = new \SoapClient($this->wsdl, [
            'soap_version' => \SOAP_1_2,
            'trace' => true,
        ]);

        return $client->UploadFlights($doc);
    }
```

As explained before, my mock should be the `$client` var.

Regards,

Comment: writing unit-test is helpful in arch-questions. you found a problem in yours. that's why the true way is to inject $client into your class. and then there will be no problems with unit-test coverage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Myxaxa's comment and after some researchs on my side, seems like the good way to do it is just to inject the soap client as a dependency.

Thanks for the answer !

Comment: Sometimes this could cause some issues if you want to build a soapclient with different parameters in different situations. That's when a `SoapClientBuilder` service might come in handy. You can inject that and mock it in your unit tests. That way you keep the client flexible and also have a good way to make a unit test for that builder.

Comment: This is a great idea. Would you care to transform your comment into an answer, so I can validate it ? :)